# How to split the user's input into words but allow this code to still work even if there are spaces?

Tags: python, input, split, words, sentence

I tried splitting the user's input so that the program detects specific words within the user input and then acts upon them. I did variables and assigned to them specific keywords that the user might enter. My program works fine if the keyword doesn't have a space before it e.g. *pin* is random. But if i put the word pin within the middle of a sentence it doesn't function properly e.g. my *pin* is random.
How can i fix this?!

```
question1= input("Do you have a problem with your device? Answer with yes or no: ")
if question1== 'no':
    print ("Please exit the troubleshooting program...")
    exit()
elif question1== 'yes':

    userquestion=input("What is your problem?")
    useranswer=userquestion.split()


    key_words1 = ("screen", "display", "monitor")
    key_words2 = ("volume", "sound", "hear", "mute", "music", "speaker", "loudspeaker")
    key_words3 = ("earphones", "headphones")
    key_words4 = ("WiFi", "wifi", "wi-fi", "speed", "internet", "connection", "network")
    key_words5 = ("switch","off", "power", "turn", "charge", "turning",)
    key_words6 = ("forgot", "pin", "forgotten", "password", "locked", "unlocked")
    key_words7 = ("storage", "installing", "memory", "sd", "lags", "lag","lagging", "slow", "install", "apps", "applications", "download")



    for word in useranswer:

        if word in key_words5:
            file = open('Power.txt', 'r')
            print (file.read())
            print()
            print("Thankyou for using this Troubleshooting program. We hope this has helped")
            exit(0)
        elif word in key_words7:
            file = open('Storage.txt', 'r')
            print (file.read())
            print()
            print("Thankyou for using this Troubleshooting program. We hope this has helped")
            exit(0)
        elif word in key_words2:
            file = open('speakers.txt', 'r')
            print (file.read())
            print()
            print("Thankyou for using this Troubleshooting program. We hope this has helped")
            exit(0)
        elif word in key_words4 :
            file = open('wifi.txt', 'r')
            print (file.read())
            print()
            print("Thankyou for using this Troubleshooting program. We hope this has helped")
            exit(0)
        elif word in key_words6:
            file = open('password.txt', 'r')
            print (file.read())
            print()
            print("Thankyou for using this Troubleshooting program. We hope this has helped")
            exit(0)
        elif word in key_words1:
            file = open('screen.txt', 'r')
            print (file.read())
            print()
            print("Thankyou for using this Troubleshooting program. We hope this has helped")
            exit(0)
        elif word in key_words3:
            file = open('headset.txt', 'r')
            print (file.read())
            print()
            print("Thankyou for using this Troubleshooting program. We hope this has helped")
            exit(0)
        else:
            print("Troubleshooting program was unable to detect your problem.")
            reporting=input("Sorry for any inconveniences- you can report you problem here. Would you like to do that?  ")
            if reporting== 'yes':
                print ("Please type in your comment below. Thank you!")
                comment=input("Report comment: ")
                exit(0)
            else:
                print("We will work on improving this program shortly")
                exit(0)
            else:
                print("Please open up the program and try again.")
            exit()
```

The program simply jumps to the end codes.

Comment: Python has `.strip()` method which operates on strings. `strip` removes white character from the head and tail of the string. E.g.: `"  \n hello  \n".strip()` gives `"hello"`. You might want to call `.strip()` on user's input before doing the check.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.strip()` method.

```
useranswer = userquestion.split()
useranswer = map(str.strip, useranswer)
```

This will remove extra spaces around the words.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach might be using python `re` module, that is regular expressions and instead of calling simple `.split()` you can call `re.split('\s+', userquestion)`. It works like normal split, but splits by regular expression. In this case `\s` stands for white characters and `+` for repetition of the `\s` character, which occurs at least once, but all the way to unlimitedly many times. More on `re` module [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

**Example**

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "My fancy   string         with many       spaces\n and tabs    "
>>> re.split('\s+', string)
['My', 'fancy', 'string', 'with', 'many', 'spaces', 'and', 'tabs', '']
```

The downside of this method, as you might have noticed is that it also added empty string `''`. This is because it has splitted `tabs` into two words `tabs` and `''`. This makes this approach dumb. There are some workarounds (one of them uses `.strip()` so that would not bring anything new to this approach), but I would go with what [@YashMehrotra's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36676622/2377489) answer. But hey, this maybe you didn't know about regexes up till now..